# What does the label field in Bitcoin-Qt mean?

Tags: bitcoin-core, paper-wallet

I tried to get involved with Bitcoin on iPad, couldn't download a wallet and thought a paper wallet was an alternative; I generated said paper wallet and used the address to buy coins.

I realized I couldn't access the coins, so I bought a macbook to download a wallet. Assumed I could just add the address from the paper wallet, but its asking for a "label."

Comment: Welcome to the Bitcoin stack exchange! To import an address into Bitcoin-Qt could take a while, especially since you have to wait for the node to download and verify the whole blockchain. You might want to use Electrum or a mobile wallet instead.

Answer (score 2):

The label is just a short, memorable name for your client to refer to that address.

It can be anything, or nothing.